# differentiability if function of two variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $g(x,y)=|\sqrt{x^2-y^2}|$, how to (rigorously) show $g$ is not differentiable everywhere on the line $x=y$ and $x=-y$.

Comment: That's not defined unless $x^2\ge y^2.$ did you mean $\sqrt {|x^2-y^2|}?$

Comment: The original question stays

Comment: What is your definition of "differentiable" in this setting then, when there are not full neighborhoods of any $(x,x)$ where the function is defined?

Comment: The usual definition Of differentiability in vector calculus applies. I do not have a computer here

Comment: No, the usual definition does not apply. That's the point.

Comment: why?Do you have a contradictory argument to prove this?

Comment: See my third comment.